# Debug Python Azure Function in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: python, azure, debugging, azure-functions, visual-studio-2022

How can I debug Azure Function in Visual Studio 2022 if the language of it is Python?

- I have the python project already in my soluion
- I can debug it but without the azure core tools. Therefore, it is pointless
- I can run it using "func start" command from cmd but I can't debug it.
- I tried to attach to the func.exe process but breakpoints are not active in this case.

I know, I should use VSCode instead. The reason of my goal is we have many c# and python functions and I would like to use Visual Studio to develop all.

Answer (score 1):

I have created an Azure function with an HTTP trigger in Visual Studio 2022 and the Azure Function Core Tools package has been installed successfully.
I set some break points in the function code and debugged the function like the below:

[image]

After I removed break points and ran the function by using the `func start` command in the terminal, it was executed successfully. check below:

[image]

**output:**

[image]

Comment: Hi Pavan, thanks for your sharing, how do you create the python azure function? using vs2022 project template or using command? On my side I can't see the project type python azure function. :)

Comment: @BowmanZhu-MSFT, I created the function with the Python runtime stack by using a command.

Comment: if possible, could you please share the detailed steps of this? :) This will be really helpful

Comment: I created one on my side but unable to hit the breakpoint, how did you do, amazing

Comment: I have already created a Python environment in my visual studio like [this](https://i.imgur.com/TtWexnl.png). I created a function with the Python runtime stack by using the `func init MyPythonFunctionApp --python`,`func new` commands in the terminal. In the function code, I put two breakpoints and then debugged the function by clicking start debugging button. After debugging, I got like [this](https://i.imgur.com/e6TVA2s.png).